# Dynamic Data Change Not Working In Html Table(asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc here i am trying to show record in a html table from the list .On second time click i want to show different record but the problem is that it is showing the same table.**Here the variable i is a static variable and intially it is set to 1**.

Here is the Code

Model class-->Employee.cs

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
  <input type="button" value="Show Grid" id="btnClick" class="btn btn-primary"  style="margin-left:10px;" />
         <div id="divTest"></div>


    @*<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />*@
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
        @*<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>*@

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btnClick').click(function () {
                $.get('@Url.Action("ShowGrid","Test")', function (data) {
                    $('#divTest').replaceWith(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

TestController

```
[HttpGet]
        public PartialViewResult ShowGrid()
        {

           List<Employee> _emplyeeList;

            if (i == 1)
            {
                _emplyeeList = new List<Employee>();
                _emplyeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Steve", ID = "1", Department = "IT", Salary = 1000 });
                _emplyeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Samules", ID = "2", Department = "Telecom", Salary = 2000 });
                _emplyeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Edward", ID = "3", Department = "Sales", Salary = 3000 });
                var a = _emplyeeList;
                ViewBag.Details = a;
                i++;
            }
            else {
                _emplyeeList = new List<Employee>();
                _emplyeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Prateek", ID = "1", Department = "IT", Salary = 1000 });
                _emplyeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Partho", ID = "2", Department = "Telecom", Salary = 2000 });
                _emplyeeList.Add(new Employee() { Name = "Pinaki", ID = "3", Department = "Sales", Salary = 3000 });
                var a = _emplyeeList;
                ViewBag.Details = a;


            }
            return PartialView("partial");

}
```

partial.cshtml

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;">
    <table id="MyTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (ViewBag.Details != null) { 
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.Details)
            {

                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @item.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.ID
                    </td>
                    <td>@item.Department</td>
                    <td>@item.Salary</td>
                </tr>

            }
            }
        </tbody>



    </table>
</div>
```

Below Image is the table which is been shown on both time click.

[image]

First time Button Click[image]

Second Time Button Click[image]

Second Time Button Click values from list[image]

Comment: no the value of i get incremented and it is coming to else block but table remains the same

Comment: Did you debug the Action method to see what is returned on both times ? (And when you click the second time, why didn't you entered `else`, did i didn't changed ?)

Comment: And where is your element with `id="divTest"`?

Comment: I am showing the debug mode pic in a moment

Comment: I meant Debugging you code, not DebugMode when running the application. Add a breakpoint on the condition `i == 1` run you application.

Comment: I have uploaded few images plss have a look .The problem is that value is coming to view bag but dont know why the old html value is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use empty() and append(data) instead of replaceWith(data)

Comment: Note you do not need the `.empty()` (`.append()` overwrites the html within the element)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of **Get** method.

**Use post method**.

Browser returns **cached** response value in get method when there is no change in request.

Or send **unique id** with every request.

There is nothing wrong in your code.

```
var ajaxid=1;
        $(function () {
            $('#btnClick').click(function () {
                $.get('@Url.Action("ShowGrid","Test")' + '?ajaxid=' + (ajaxid++), function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#divTest').replaceWith(data);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have tried using post method but result is the same

Comment: Can you give me some example on how to send unique code on every request

Comment: take any variable at client side and increment there. and send it with ajax. First check what is in response of ajax.

Comment: Stil it is same as it was earlier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163055/discussion-between-hardik-viradiya-and-prateek-ghosh).

Comment: I am getting nothing only at the time page load it come to debug point and after pressing f10 show the page and after button click it doesnot comes to the debugger point